# "short message transfer rejected" m590 device

Tags: runtime-error, send, gprs

Im trying to get a M590 circuit to send a GSM/GPRS SMS,

I have communication with the cirtuit using serial communication using  PUTTY.exe

on power on the M590 starts up, giving the following printout:

MODEM: STARTUP
+PBREADY

It has registered to the GSM network since

+AT+CSQ             ;given as input gives
22,2

+AT+CREG? 
+CREG: 0,1

to sen an SMS i enter the following (Ok is the response recieved)

+AT+CMGF=1   ;ie set mode text
OK

+AT+CSCS="GSM"   ;ie GSM coding of chars
OK

+AT+CMGS="+46739550618"     ; the sending command (my phone ;)

> "hii" ctrl-z
>   ... it goes away a while

ERROR

Comment: the "hi" is proceeded with a >  which seem to generate the beige background :) also the OK should be on next line as response...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ctrl z, you can try : push alt  then 026 and then release  alt. It did work for me.